# segementcontrol addUnderlineForSelectedSegment not working in iOS 13

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol, ios13

```
func addUnderlineForSelectedSegment() {
    removeBorder()
    let underlineWidth: CGFloat = self.bounds.size.width / CGFloat(self.numberOfSegments)
    let underlineHeight: CGFloat = 3.0
    let underlineXPosition = CGFloat(selectedSegmentIndex * Int(underlineWidth))
    let underLineYPosition = self.bounds.size.height + 10.0

    let underlineFrame = CGRect(x: underlineXPosition, y: underLineYPosition, width: underlineWidth, height: underlineHeight)
    let underline = UIView(frame: underlineFrame)

    // underline.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 67/255, green: 129/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1.0)
    print("underline:\(underline)")
    underline.backgroundColor = .red
    underline.tag = 1
    self.addSubview(underline)
    didAddSubview(underline)
}
```

Comment: Why not apply underline text attributes to the selected state? No need to mess with trying to modify views. It's almost always a bad idea to fight a private API.

Comment: Ok thanks let me try

Answer (score 0):

I got a bug of the same kind with you.
It's work in older version but doesn't work in currently iOS 13.
Spend all day for fixing this stupid thing, and one line fixing everything.

Try to set **clipsToBounds to false** after removeBorder().

```
func addUnderlineForSelectedSegment(){
    removeBorder()
    clipsToBounds = false
    let underlineWidth: CGFloat = Size.Screen.width / CGFloat(numberOfSegments)
    let underlineHeight: CGFloat = 1.0
    let underlineXPosition = CGFloat(selectedSegmentIndex * Int(underlineWidth))
    let underLineYPosition = bounds.size.height - 1.0
    let underlineFrame = CGRect(x: underlineXPosition, y: underLineYPosition, width: underlineWidth, height: underlineHeight)
    let underline = UIView(frame: underlineFrame)
    underline.backgroundColor = Color.default80.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
    underline.tag = 1
    addSubview(underline)
}
```